Semimetric on pointed rational extension of reals
While searching for missing entries in $\pi$-Base I encountered semimetrizability of pointed rational extension of reals.
The space in question is $\mathbb R$ but with topology generated by sets of the form $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap\mathbb Q\cup\{x\}$.
So the question is whether there exists a semimetric $d$ ("metric" without the triangle inequality; see this thread) on $\mathbb R$ defining this topology (convergence in semimetric = convergence in topology).
My attempt on constructing appropriate semimetric is the following:

$d(x,y)=1$, $d(x,x)=0$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, $x\neq y$,
$d(x,a/b)=d(a/b,x)=\max\{1/b,|x-a/b|\}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $b>0$, $(a,b)=1$, $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$,
$d(p,q)=|p-q|$ for $p,q\in \mathbb Q$.

Properties of $d$:

For $a/b\in \mathbb Q$ the "ball" of radius $1/|b|$ contains no irrational number.
For $x\in \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ the "ball" of radius $<1$ is contained in $\mathbb Q\cup\{x\}$.
A sequence of irrational numbers cannot be convergent in $d$, unless it is eventually constant.
For sequences of rational numbers $d$-limits are exactly those from the standard topology.

Is there any point I am missing? Is there a smooth way to complete the argument?

Have not thought properly on Pointed irrational extension of reals in this context though. I suspect it is not semimetrizable.

The argument looks correct. I don’t immediately see a way to simplify this, though. The only way seems to be just working through the details. (It may be easier to use the definition that semimetric balls form a neighborhood basis at every point, instead of using the definition on convergence.)

Pointed irrational extension of reals is not semimetrizable, as you suspected. I’ll add an MSE Q&A for this when I have time later.

I have written down a proof of a more general result here, which also contains a result that in particular implies the pointed irrational extension of reals is not semimetrizable.
